# How to update the records from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have around 88k records in another table like **ac**. I want to update one column of the table **ac** into main table like **tbl**. 
Eg- Table **tbl**  sample records like

**col1** **col2** **col3** **col4**

```
abc  dhj  123  ab12
def  bhv  456  ds34
ghi  hwj  789  hj46
jkl  yuh  012  ke28
```

In table **ac** sample records like

**col1** **col3**`

```
cba   123
fed   456
ihg   789
lkj   012
```

How to update the **tbl** value from **ac** table. So that the record look like

**col1** **col2** **col3** **col4**

```
cba  dhj  123  ab12
fed  bhv  456  ds34
ihg  hwj  789  hj46
lkj  yuh  012  ke28
```

Comment: Have you attempted an update or merge, and what problems did you have with your code?

Comment: Why is the 4th COL1 value updated to LKJ? COL3 values differ (012 vs. 210). Should you also check for permutations? (I hope not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do a [correlated update](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5__I2189758):

```
update tbl
set col1 = (select col1 from ac where ac.col3 = tbl.col3)
where exists (select col1 from ac where ac.col3 = tbl.col3);

3 rows updated.

select * from tbl;

COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
---- ---- ---- ----
cba  dhj  123  ab12
fed  bhv  456  ds34
ihg  hwj  789  hj46
jkl  yuh  012  ke28
```

Or a [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/MERGE.html):

```
merge into tbl
using ac
on (ac.col3 = tbl.col3)
when matched then update set tbl.col1 = ac.col1;

3 rows merged.

select * from tbl;

COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
---- ---- ---- ----
cba  dhj  123  ab12
fed  bhv  456  ds34
ihg  hwj  789  hj46
jkl  yuh  012  ke28
```

In both cases the fourth row isn't affected as there is no matching record in `ac`, as @Littlefoot pointed out. The `merge` just doesn't find a match; for the `update` version the `where exists` clause prevents values being set to null if there is no matchign row to update from. If the fourth row in `ac` was `012` instead of `210` they would all be updated, in both versions.